# Como funciona o GET com AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho uma páginação `AJAX` que esta funcionando, na verdade sem funciona melhor, estou tentando entender como o `AJAX` trabalha com a url para a paginação funcionar corretamente.

O que acontece é que na paginação normal, sem `AJAX` cada um dos links funcionavam normal, mais especificamente o prev e o next: prev 1 2 3 4 next, já que o `GET` estava na mesma url.

Mas com `AJAX` somente a sequencia de numeros funciona. Se eu colocar  `$next=$current_page+1;` a variavel current_page sempre recebe a url atual sem o valor de `$_GET["page_no"]` então com `AJAX` se eu estiver na página 8 e clicar em next na paginação, por aparentemente não estar reconhecendo o `GET` na url atual, o next vai pra pagina 1 ao invés da página 9.

Não sei se isso tem a ver com eu estar trabalhando com `data-haref`, ao inves de `href`.

Agradeço ajuda

class.crud.php

```
public function paginglink($query,$records_per_page)
{

    $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    $total_no_of_records = $stmt->rowCount();

    if($total_no_of_records > 0)
    {
        ?><ul class="pagination"><?php
        $total_no_of_pages=ceil($total_no_of_records/$records_per_page);
        $current_page=1;
        if(isset($_GET["page_no"]))
        {
            $current_page=$_GET["page_no"];
        }
        if($current_page!=1)
        {
            $previous =$current_page-1;
            echo "<li class='page-item'><a href='#' class='page-link' data-href='".$self."?page_no=1'>First</a></li>";
            echo "<li class='page-item'><a href='#' class='page-link' data-href='".$self."?page_no=".$previous."'>Back</a></li>";

        }
        for($i=1;$i<=$total_no_of_pages;$i++)
        {
            if($i==$current_page)
            {
                echo "<li class='page-item'><a href='#' class='page-link' data-href='".$self."?page_no=".$i."' style='color:red;'>".$i."</a></li>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<li class='page-item'><ahref='#' class='page-link' data-href='".$self."?page_no=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>";
            }
        }
        if($current_page!=$total_no_of_pages)
        {
            $next=$current_page+1;
            echo "<li class='page-item'><a href='#' class='page-link' data-href='".$self."?page_no=".$next."'>Next</a></li>";
            echo "<li class='page-item'><a href='#' class='page-link' data-href='".$self."?page_no=".$total_no_of_pages."'>Last</a></li>";
        }
        ?></ul><?php
    }
}
```

**AJAX**

```
$('.page-link').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   var url = $(this).data('href');

   $.ajax({
         url: url,
         success: function (response) {

           var html = $('<h1/>', {html : response}).find('#paginacao-ajax');
           $('#paginacao-ajax').html( html )              

         }
   });
})
```

Comment: "Não sei se isso tem a ver com eu estar trabalhando com data-haref, ao inves de href", não vejo nenhum `data-href` no código que colocou.

Comment: @Isac atualizei o código

Comment: E os urls que estão a ser chamados aqui `var url = $(this).data('href');` estão corretos ? faça um `console.log` desse valor para confirmar

Comment: tirei os `href="#"` deixei apenas `data-href` e o que esta sendo capturado pelo trecho `var url = $(this).data('href');` é o `data-href`

Comment: @isac no console esta dando ok para todos os numeros da paginação ex: `/pagina.php?page_no=1`, mas para next e prev esta dando `/undefined` na url  e ao lado a descrição de erro é 404 not found,

Comment: Parece que já está a descobrir o problema. Verifique se o seu `$current_page` tem o valor correto com `var_dump` ou semelhantes

Comment: `var_dump` retorna  `int`, `print_r retorna`  1

Comment: Antes ou depois do `$current_page=$_GET["page_no"];` ? Convém testar depois dessa linha para garantir que está a ler valores corretos do `$_GET`.
Aproveite e confirme também o valor de `$next` e/ou `$previous` para garantir que estão certos antes de chegar ao `echo`

Comment: @Isac testei antes e depois o resultado é o mesmo

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa desmonstrar qual sua página atual ao fazer a requisição, adicione um atributo informando isso aos botões 'next', 'prev', 'last', 'first'.

```
 echo "<li class='page-item'><a href='#' class='page-link' data-href='".$self."?page_no=".$next."' data-actual-page='$actual_page'>Next</a></li>";
```

E na sua requisição, recupere a página e transmita:

```
$('.page-link').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   var url = $(this).data('href');
   var actual_page = $(this).data('actual-page');
   $.ajax({
         url: url,
         type:GET,
         data:{actual_page:actual_page},
         success: function (response) {

           var html = $('<h1/>', {html : response}).find('#paginacao-ajax');
           $('#paginacao-ajax').html( html )              

         }
   });
})
```

PS: Eu particularmente prefiro usa POST em requisições AJAX, mas não acho que faça alguma diferença de fato pra paginações simples